# factoryImplementation in Polymer 2.0

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

In Polymer 1.0 there was the possibility to detect if a polymer element was created by contructor, the function that was triggered when the element was created named factoryImpl().

I wan't to do the same in Polymer 2.0, if i create an element via a constructor, a standard function should be triggered and should do something. Does anyone done this before and can give a hint to do that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use constructor:

```
class TestEle extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'test-ele'; }
      constructor() {
        super()
        console.log('created')
      }
//...
```

You should see 'created' logged whenever you create TestEle

```
<test-ele> </test-ele> // created
or 
document.createElement('test-ele') // created
or
new TestEle() // created
```

// Edited as per the comments below.

I couldn't find any information on the legacy factoryImpl equivalent in 2.0. However, there's a work around you could try.

```
 class TestEle extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'test-ele'; }
      constructor(c) {
        super()
        console.log('created')
        if(c) {
           console.log('created using constructor')
        }
      }
...
```

```
<test-ele> </test-ele> // created
or 
document.createElement('test-ele') // created
or
new TestEle(true) // created and created using constructor
```

Comment: Yes thats right! But I want that the constructor, only be triggered when i created the element via the command new TestEle(), and not when i  create the Element via writing it to the document Tree by Hand, with this solution the Constructor is triggered Everytime as you write it! It should be only triggered in the last two ways you have write down

Comment: I don't think the legacy factoryImpl is supported in 2.0 
However, there is a workaround you can apply to identify if an element is created using constructor I.e new TestEle(). Check the updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot this was also my approach, i hoped there where a better approach